# How do I move the navigation tabs in the navbarPage layout in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am fairly experienced in R, but not at all in any sort of web development. I am trying to use Shiny.

I am just testing it out and have the following for the UI:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("This is some awesome testing!!!",
                   tabPanel("Plot"),
                   tabPanel("Summary" ),
                   navbarMenu("More",
                              tabPanel("Table"),
                              tabPanel("About")
                   )
))
```

This produces a page with a navigation bar as below, but notice the navigation tabs are in the middle of the page. Is there a way to move it to the left? So it would be all the way against the left side of the page?

I just noticed resizing the window moves it around some and helps move it to the left more, but is there a way to make it 'stick' to the left side of the window?

[image]

I imagine there is some way to force it through some css or html or something , but I am not even sure if those are the right terms. Again, I have zero experience in web development.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will need to start messing around with css to effectively modify the default shiny outputs.  Here, it looks like the only `div` that needs to be modified is the first `container`.  Since there isn't much css, it can be added with `tags` fairly easily,

```
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        navbarPage("This is some awesome testing!!!",
                   tabPanel("Plot"),
                   tabPanel("Summary" ),
                   navbarMenu("More",
                              tabPanel("Table"),
                              tabPanel("About")
                              ),
                   tags$head(tags$style('
                       nav .container:first-child {
                           margin-left:10px; width: 100%;
                       }'))
                   )),
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
)
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!